# How can I make my registration test case run 5 times creating a new username each time?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have a registration test that creates one account but I want to add a loop to this so that if will run 5 times in a row entering different usernames and email address, I already have the usernames I want to use stored in a seperate python file. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. There are different approaches but below is the simple approach.

Store all the required details in the list and then iterate.

```
users = [['user1','pass1'],['user2','pass2'],['user3','pass3'],['user5','pass5'],['user5','pass5']]

for user in users:
    # get user name and use in registration
    userName = user[0]
    # get password and use in registration
    passWord = user[1]
    print (userName + ":" + passWord)
```

Comment: But OP mentioned _I already have the usernames I want to use stored in a seperate python file_

Comment: @PMcg1983, please share the file that you have the data.